# How do we assign an object to a newly created object in drool

Tags: drools

I am new to drools and have a scenario where I have to assign an object1 to object2 and change one of the field value of object2 and pass it further so that I don't loose object1 and can use object1 accordingly. I have the below code but it throws an exception. Please can someone let me know how we can assign an object to newly created Object.

```
rule "example"
when
$customerObject : Customer(nameOfBank=="AXIS",salary>=70000);
$newObject:Customer()
$newObject:$customerObject;
then
$customerObject.setIsAligibleforLoan("Yes");
$customerObject.setRateOfInterest(12); 
$newObject.setDocumentNeeded("Yes");
DocumentCheck($newObject);
halt();
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule, as written, doesn't make much sense. What is `$newObject:$customerObject` supposed to be doing?

Variables that you declare in your `when` clause are only scoped to the rule, there's no "passing it along."

If you want to create a *copy* of an object in working memory, modify it, and then have other rules key off of the values in the copy, then you want to use `insert`.

```
rule "Example 1"
when
  $original: Example( name == "something", value < 0 )
then
  // make a copy
  $copy = new Example( $original.getName(), original.getValue() ); 

  // make some modifications
  $copy.setOtherField( "X" );

  // insert into working memory
  insert( $copy );
end
```

Now you will have 2 items in working memory (the original and the copied-and-modified). `insert` will reevaluate all subsequent rules to figure out if they are still valid / are now valid for firing. Previous rules will not be reevaluated.

If you want to refire *all* rules, use `update` instead of `insert`. You can remove an object from working memory with `retract`.

Comment: Are you sure this will not cause an infinite loop? For every `Example` you are inserting a new one that will trigger the exact same rule (unless you include some constraint in the rule itself to exclude the clones in some way)

Comment: `insert` won't loop because it won't refire the original rule that triggered it. `update` will, unless the rule is updated to be no-longer-valid for firing.